# How can change two 1d list array to 2 dimensional list array?

Tags: c#, arraylist

`List<int> Boxsize = {3,1,6,7}`

`List<int> Boxunit = {2,7,4,9}`

`List<List<int>> Allbox = new List<List<int>>();`

I try to make 2-dimensional list  as like each element  (Boxsize[i], Boxunit[i])
because Boxsize, Boxunit will variable

ex.

`List<List<int>> Allbox = {{3,2} , {1,7} , {6,4} , {7,9}}`

```
for (int i = 0; i < Boxsize.Count; i++)
{
    Allbox[i].Add(Boxunit[i]);
    Allbox[i].Add(Boxsize[i]);    
}
```

It doesn't work, and I am getting an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Would you help me this?

Comment: Like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CHs77P ?

Comment: Thanks really appreciate it!  I add code 'Allbox.Add(new List<int>());' It works

Comment: Notice, I did change the order of `Allbox[i].Add(Boxunit[i]);` and `Allbox[i].Add(Boxsize[i]);` because the output wasn't identical to the one you have shown in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply initialize the nested list item inside the for.

```
var innerList = new List<int>();

innterList.Add(Boxunit[i]);
innterList.Add(Boxsize[i]);

Allbox.Add(innerList);
```

You could, though just use a `Dictionary` or a custom class.

Answer (score 0):

Using dictionary instead of list may be more useful.

```
List<int> Boxsize =new() { 3, 1, 6, 7 };
List<int> Boxunit =new() { 2, 7, 4, 9 };
Dictionary<int, int> s = new();
for (int i = 0; i < Boxsize.Count; i++)
{
    s.Add(Boxsize[i], Boxunit[i]);
}
```